# Add templates for common notes & warnings

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation

With many topics, there are a few common warnings or tips that keep cropping up.

We should allow users to create templates for things that could be used in multiple places.

Example templates for Git:

<kbd>**Warning:** This command **permanently** deletes history.     *[safe version](http://_)*</kbd>

<kbd>**Info:** This command can be undone.     *[how?](http://_)*</kbd>

<kbd>**Warning:** This command changes history, avoid using it on a public branch.      *[why?](http://_)*</kbd>          vs.       [current example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/46342?draftId=39807)

---

This would:

- Save people time by not repeating themselves (DRY),
- Make the docs safer and more informative because its easier for editors to add tips,
- Make the docs more succinct through a convention where tips include the bare minimum with a link to read more (compare the last example above: proposed vs. [current](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/46342?draftId=39807)).

Comment: Right. Add a list at the bottom of the intro topic (under an expand/collapse header) and then add a checkbox list at the bottom of each example on edit.

Comment: It might also be useful to make these expandable, so that the `safe version`, `how?`, and `why?` are right there and don’t take you away from the example.

Comment: (off topic) in the future, you might be interested in [this link](http://gstatic.com/generate_204) for example links.

Comment: Someone should tell Community♦ that Documentation has been shut down

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, we've refocused our efforts on [understanding what makes for good documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation). One element of that will be extracting common patterns such as those you mention. In particular, good documentation highlights potential traps using a feature and gives actionable troubleshooting advice. It's entirely possible we'll end up with some warnings that need to be used a number of places.

That said, I think these sorts of templates should be avoided as long as possible. We've had experience with [stock annotations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted) and it seems generally a better idea to encourage people to use their own words rather then provide a template. Practically speaking, people tend to gloss over stock warnings rather than take notice if overused. (For instance, I no longer pay much attention to Wikipedia's [citation needed template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Citation_needed).) So instead of a button, you're probably better off using a bit of bold to get your point across:

> **Warning:** This command **permanently** deletes history. If that's not what you want, try the [safe version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/355/rebasing/4357/pushing-after-a-rebase#t=201706090029035021043).

It's not that many keystrokes and you can effectively reuse the details with a simple link.

We will need to be a bit more explicit in our guidance about how to include gotchas in examples. It's always frustrating to find an outdated answer that's been accepted on Stack Overflow and is no longer best practice. Documentation's [versions feature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions) helps with that. Perhaps it would makesense to provide a generic version of *The TeXbook*'s [dangerous bend symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312120/5871):

[image: Dangerous bend]

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my idea for how it might look. Please comment with suggestions for improvements.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.example-tip .example-tip-toggle', function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents('.example-tip').toggleClass('active').find('.example-tip-description-content').slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.example-tip .example-tip-toggle {
  float: right;
}

.example-tip {
  width: 500px !important;
  background: #eff0f1;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #c8ccd0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.example-tip.warning {
  background: #FFF8DC;
}
.example-tip.info {
  background: #DBE2FF;
}

.example-tip .example-tip-description {
  border-top: 1px solid #c8ccd0;
  margin: 8px -8px -8px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
.example-tip .example-tip-description-content {
  margin: 8px 0;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=5616c4b48a09">

<div class="example-tip warning">
  <strong>Warning</strong>: This command permanently deletes history. <a class="example-tip-toggle" href="#">safe version</a>
  <div class="example-tip-description">
    <div class="example-tip-description-content" style="display: none">The safe version can be acquired by bribing unicorns.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-tip info">
  <strong>Info</strong>: This command can be undone. <a class="example-tip-toggle" href="#">how?</a>
    <div class="example-tip-description">
    <div class="example-tip-description-content" style="display: none"><em>Hint</em>: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>&lt;kbd&gt;</kbd></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-tip warning">
  <strong>Warning</strong>: This command changes history, avoid using it on a public branch. <a class="example-tip-toggle" href="#">why?</a>
    <div class="example-tip-description">
      <div class="example-tip-description-content" style="display: none">
        <p><em>Stolen from <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/218/getting-started-with-git/811/create-your-first-repository-then-add-and-commit-files#t=201610291928273144421">SO Docs</a>.</em></p><p>At the command line, first verify that you have Git installed:</p><p>On all operating systems:</p><pre><code>git --version</code></pre><p>On UNIX-like operating systems, you can also run this command:</p><pre><code>which git</code></pre><p>If nothing is returned, or the command is not recognized, you may have to install Git on your system by downloading and running the installer. See the <a href="https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git" rel="nofollow">Git homepage</a> for installation instructions.</p><p>After installing Git, it may be a good time to set up a username and email address: see <a class='doc-link' href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/218/getting-started-with-git/6939/setting-your-user-name-and-email">Setting your username and email</a> for instructions. You'll have to do this <em>before</em> making a commit.</p><p>Once Git is installed, navigate to the directory that you want to place under version control and create an empty Git repository:</p><pre><code>git init</code></pre><p>This creates a hidden folder, <code>.git</code>, which contains the plumbing needed for Git to work. Next, tell Git that you want to place all files from the current directory under version control:</p><pre><code>git add .</code></pre><p>This will <a class='doc-link' href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/244/staging">&quot;stage&quot;</a> all files to be added to version control, making them ready to be committed in your maiden commit.</p><p>If you don't want all the files to be added to version control, create a file named <code>.gitignore</code> and <a class='doc-link' href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/245/ignoring-files-and-folders#t=201607281145105871327">edit it</a> before running the <code>add</code> command so that these files will not be included.</p><p>Commit all the files that have been added, along with a commit message:</p><pre><code>git commit -m "Initial commit"</code></pre><p>This creates a new <a class='doc-link' href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/323/committing">commit</a> with the given message. A commit is a bit like a save or snapshot of your entire project. You can now <a class='doc-link' href="http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/2600/pushing">push</a>, or upload, it to a repository now, and later, you can jump back to it if necessary.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Markdown:

```
[tip:Deletes History {
can be acquired by bribing unicorns.
}]
[tip:Can Undo {
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>&lt;kbd&gt;</kbd>
}]
[tip:Rewrites History {
}]
```

[/documentation/*<tag>*/tips](http://gstatic.com/generate_204):

```css
input.link {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

/*****/

ul {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=5616c4b48a09">

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Deletes History" placeholder="Short name"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="One-line Description" value="This command permanently deletes history." size=38>
    <input type="text" class="link" value="why?" placeholder="Expand link" size=1>
    <br>
    <textarea placeholder="Markdown allowed. Use ${} to include templated data.">The safe version ${}</textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Can Undo" placeholder="Short name"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="One-line Description" value="This command can be undone." size=38>
    <input type="text" class="link" value="how?" placeholder="Expand link" size=1>
    <br>
    <textarea placeholder="Markdown allowed. Use ${} to include templated data.">Hint: ${}</textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Deletes History" placeholder="Short name"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="One-line Description" value="Warning: This command changes history, avoid using it on a public branch." size=38>
    <input type="text" class="link" value="why?" placeholder="why?" size=1>
    <br>
    <textarea placeholder="Markdown allowed. Use ${} to include templated data.">(I’m too lazy to copy-paste the whole thing here)</textarea>
  </li>
</ul>
```