# Documentation Reorganization Issues

Tags: discussion, documentation

I'm finding reorganizing of documentation to be incredibly difficult with the way changes are reviewed. My specific case involves [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/7960/eloquent-relationship). Currently all available examples are used (seems to be capped at 6). One of the relationships is missing from this list, which is polymorphic relations; however, trying to move them all into one example gets rejected by people for not offering any improvements (other members of SO have tried).

If I were to try and delete one of the examples to make space it would inevitably also be rejected for not being a useful edit. It seems very difficult with the current setup for a group of people to come to a decision to reorganize examples. Each example gets edited and reviewed individually so a big picture edit seems difficult. Is there a way to edit a whole section?

Comment: Sounds like the topic is too broad. Note that there is a "discussion" feature in docs now, but, that'd mean you would need to somehow get the other users to use it too (would be easy if they're already following it)

Comment: Yeah I've added discussion but when another user saw the discussion and tried to reorganize it was like instantly rejected. It seems like once some information I'm not even sure how you could split topics without someone rejecting the new topic as already available elsewhere.

Comment: It might take finding a user that can bypass the review process for a change that might be taken as destroying content, even if the net result is better oganization and more content.

Comment: One of the examples is called "introduction." Remove that one and *add an introduction.* There's an entirely separate area for that. 
https://s10.postimg.org/athm3gzd5/intro1.png
https://s10.postimg.org/8avx2sdmx/intro.png

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full answer for you just yet, but organization is something we are [actively researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation). The 6-example limit was a hack to try to push contributions toward smaller, more focused topics. For the moment, I'd suggest starting a new topic.

That said, you *can* edit the entire topic. Once you start editing a draft, go to another example and click the "edit" link:

[image: Edit link]

That'll open up an edit window for that example too. It'll also give you a link to delete the example, if that's what's needed. In any case, once the change is proposed, all edits to the entire topic will be reviewed at once.

(This isn't the most intuitive UI.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jon, I actually just saw your post Tearing Down the Structure of Documentation right after I put this up. Appreciate everything you all are doing, Documentation has been a great resource.