# Tags for documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Why are there no tags for documented articles. If I search for *Linq* I get 3 results: *linq* , *linq-to-sql* and *linq-to-xml (proposed)*. But under *C#* somewhere I found this article: [Linq to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/9405/linq-to-objects#t=201705291401326476727).

Why not have tags like in questions for documentation too. I wonder how many such documented articles lie hidden under another topic.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, this sort of problem is just the sort of thing we hope to address by [tearing down the structure of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation). Our search isn't up to snuff *within* a tag and it doesn't look outside of a tag. That means there are many topics (such as Linq and regular expressions) that are repeated over and over again. Not only are you trapped within a tag, there's tons of repetition of the same material rather than iterative improvements on canonical topics.

We don't yet have a solution, but I did want to acknowledge there's a problem. As we produce prototypes, I'll be checking to see if they help make topics more findable across tags.